# Get user rankings based on points from database

Tags: mysql, sorting

I've created a website where members collect points to get a reward at the end of the contest.

I want to create a page that shows the top 10 members who have the most points. I've tried a few pieces of SQL code but there is no result at the end.

Database name: `dbtest`
Table name: `users`
Columns: `ID | username | email | password | points`

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a SQL statement of

```
select * from users order by points desc limit 10
```

You order the users table by points descending, then take the top 10 results, which will be the users with the most points.

The inclusion of the password column raises a red flag for me - I hope you have the password stored in a secure manner?